# ExtJS 4. The best way to prevent JsonStore load more than once for specific set of parameters

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, jsonstore

I have two grid panels which used JsonStore. When row selected in first grid related data loads to second grid using `store2.load(...)`. This works fine.

I have ability to add some rows to second grid (store2), without sending to server (this is requirement). But when I select other row in first grid and then return to initial row the added data is not present. This is because sore2 reloaded from server.

So now I am trying to find the best way to prevent second store reload and use local data.
Any ideas?

During investigation I find property  `single: true` but can't find any documentation about it.

Comment: working on it. I will add solution after that (I trying to load all records to second store and use filter).

Answer (score 0):

After you switched from second to first row in your master grid the data in store2 is gone because this switching triggered store2.load(). One option would be to check if store2 contains some dirty rows and prevent store2.load() if this is the case. But with this solution your second grid will never update any more if you changed some data in it.

To resolve this issue the only solution I can see is a third data store with a local storage proxy (e.g. proxy: memory). This store holds all modified/added rows for each master row from store1. Now you would have to check on every row change if there is data for this row in store3 and add this to the data of store2 after store2.load() has been processed. You could use the load event fired from store2 to do this.